# Doing two things at once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, loops

Say I have an infinite javascript loop which is incrementing a number and displaying it on the screen. I also have a button on the screen that pauses the timer.

If javascript is going through this infinite loop, how can I get the pause button to stop the loop? Does that require "threads" of some kind? I was thinking of just having a `$('#pause').click()` tigger hooked up to the counter object.

Comment: If you have an infinite loop then you will hang your browser. (worker threads can be used, however, in browsers that support them). The question is, **why** do you have an infinite loop?

Comment: why not use `setInterval()`

Comment: Are you doing the "loop" via timeout?  If so, try clearTimeout() (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp), otherwise you need a conditional comment... but I don't know your code.  Can you post it?

Comment: Please don't use w3schools.com. See http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never go into an infinite loop in client-side JavaScript, period. Normally counting to infinity is done using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) or [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout), which allows other code such as the click handler to run between timer ticks.

It is true that you can use [web workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker) (i.e. multithreaded JavaScript) if the client browser supports them, but you don't need this just for an infinite counter.

Comment: Ah `setInterval` seems like a much better way of doing things. Are there any race conditions involved in doing so? What if a button `click` triggers at the same time as another interval is fired?

Comment: @MaxMackie: One of the two events will get to run first, and it will run to completion before the other one starts running. Race conditions are sorted out by the time your JS code gets to see the light of day.